# Preserving an ordered index during dbm-gorm-diff

Tags: grails, grails-orm, database-migration, grails-domain-class

I have a Domain class mapped to a MySQL table via the database-migration plugin.  For performance reasons, I needed an index created with attributes in a specific order.

Every time I do a dbm-gorm-diff, however, the generated code wants to drop my index and re-create it using the default ordering.

I get that currently grails cannot specify an arbitrary index ordering.  However, is there any way to tell the migrations plugin to ignore the index?

Comment: Its a hack but if you look at the database table DATABASECHANGELOG.  It has all the changes executed and the plugin uses that to figure out what's changed.  Add in an entry in there to "trick" it that it has already created the index already and it won't do it again.